# checking of removable discontinuity for sinusoidal function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

before   i will post  itself question,let us  consider following definition

[image]

now consider following question and part $c$

[image]

related to part  $c$, we have in square brackets  $sin(x)$   for $sin(x)$ greater number less the or equal to $sin(x)$ will be itself $sin(x)$ right? i dont really understood one part, at $a=\pi$

$sin(a)=0$   right  ?so if it is discontinuous at this point, clearly it is not removable right?but why it  is discontinuous?

Answer (score 0):

Take a sequence of points converging to pi from above and a sequence from below. Both sequences have different limits so $a $ is not removable.

Comment: why do you think  so my friend

Comment: I was wrong originally. To be continuous, every sequence must converge to the same limit and that limit must be $f(a)$. To have a removable discontinuity, every sequence must converge to the same thing, and that limit is not $f(a)$.